# Retaining state in tab view

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a app with 3 tabs. Each tab is a instance of some widget. Now whats happening is everytime i swipe tabs then the data in tab is reloaded. I want to load data only when the tab is opened for the first time, but if the moves to next tab and then return to previous tab it should not reload the data but show the old state.

Following Widget is instantiated for each tab.

```
class CustomersScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomersScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  CustomersScreenState createState() => CustomersScreenState();
}

class CustomersScreenState extends State<CustomersScreen> {
  Firestore fireStore;
  List<Customer> customers = [];
  bool isLoading = false; // track if customers fetching
  bool hasMore = true; // flag for more products available or not
  final int documentLimit = 10; // documents to be fetched per request
  Map<String, Tuple2> filters = Map();
  DocumentSnapshot lastDocument; // next token
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fireStore = Firestore.instance;
    print("Doing initial load");
    loadData();
  }
```

Questions1:

- How do i prevent data from being reloaded on every tab swipe as described above? One thing i can think of is just use a flag isDataloaded and then load/not load the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` at the end of `State<CustomerScreen>`.

It should be something like

```
class CustomersScreenState extends State<CustomersScreen> 
with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
    @override
    bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

    .... Your code here
}
```

Comment: That worked. For whatever reason initState method was called everytime after the tab was reshow. This stopped after ur suggested change. Why so?

Comment: That's weird. I dont remember experiencing the same thing as I'm using tabbar and pageview in my project right now. Anyway, you should create another question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using TabBarView ? If not, [click here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs) to see how to. It preloads the tabs and retains their state.